# How to store gas on little pulsejet plane?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am thinking about building small plane with a pulsejet but the engine would need to be roughly 2 cm in diameter. Is it even possible to fit something to store gas on that sized plane? At least for like 10 seconds of running.

Comment: Hi! It would be great if you could perhaps narrow down the question a little... have you been able to work out roughly how much total gas you will need for the necessary thrust? It's very difficult to engineer a solution without a rough estimate of the requirements. Scaling the engine might be your first task.

Comment: "Gas" may mean petrol or eg "propane". Either are possible and petrol is easy. A used "sparklet" CO2 cylinder from a soda syphon os softdrink CO2 dispenser would probably work for Propane. You'd have to check with a engineer re safety, and the chances of this being an approved or certifiable use are "very small" [tm]. If gas = petrol then model aircraft fuel systems are a logical place to start.

Comment: The small butane soldering torches do exactly that. Whether they meet your weight goals is another matter... https://www.machinemart.co.uk/shop/product/details/cbt5k-butane-gas-torch-kit

Answer (score 1):

buy a propane lighter refiller cartridge, these are about 1" in diameter and 5" long. make the cartridge part of the fuselage.